# How to access dynamic C++ array variable, belonging to an object, with Python?

Tags: python, c++, numpy, cython

I have a C++ class with a variable that is a dynamic array. It is extremely simple, currently only for testing purposes:

```
class testClass {

public:
    int *x;

    testClass();
    ~testClass();
};
```

The variable `x` is initialised with some values, currently through the constructor. I am trying to write a python wrapper code for the C++ class through [Cython](http://cython.org/) that can access `x`. How can I do this?

Best thing would be to be able to access the variable without copying a lot of data, as `x` might be large. Can I access it **as a numpy** array?

Example, that it behave as **numpy** array, that could be read only for instance? I want to be able to use the data in `x` in other calculations with python, so a **numpy** array is preferred.

I suppose I could make a `GET` method that initialize a **numpy** array, passes it it to the `GET` method and populate it with the data from `x` with a loop, but this would copy the data, and does not seem very elegant. Hoping for a better solution.

I have tried with a static array, and found a solution that sort of worked. If `x` is static, I could do the following in a `.pyx` file:

```
cdef extern from "testClass.h":
    cdef cppclass testClass:
        testClass()
        int x[5]

cdef class pyTestClass:
    cdef testClass *thisptr

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.thisptr = new testClass()
    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr

    property x:
        def __get__(self):
            return self.thisptr.x
```

If I access `x` in Python, I will get a Python list with the values back.

---

How to access dynamic C++ array variable, belonging to an object, with Python?

Comment: Your class seems pretty strange because you aren't storing a length/shape value. How do you know how many values are in the array?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this example](https://gist.github.com/GaelVaroquaux/1249305) that explains how to expose arrays allocated in C to numpy without  data copies. The relevant line to create, for instance, a 1D numpy array of integers in Cython with already allocated data is,

```
ndarray = np.PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, shape, np.NPY_INT, data_pointer)
```

See the corresponding [Numpy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/c-info.how-to-extend.html#c.PyArray_SimpleNewFromData).